# WiFi P2P with Android using wpa_cli in linux

Tags: linux, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to establish connection between my laptop and Android device using wpa_cli.
I tried differen combinations of wpa_cli commands to connect but coud not do so.
The commands I am running on my laptop are as follows:

First combination:

1. p2p_find 10

   *Output:P2P-DEVICE-FOUND -------*
2. p2p_peers

   *Output: Android device addr -------*
3. p2p_prov_disc  pbc

   *Output: My laptop is visible on android peer devices list -------*
4. p2p_group_add

   *Output: AP-ENABLED  -------*
5. wps_pbc

   *Output: WPS-PBC-ACTIVE -------*

After running these commands, I am getting following error:

```
*"P2P-DEVICE-LOST p2p_dev_addr=-----
 WPS-TIMEOUT"*
```

Second combination:

1. p2p_find 10

   *Output:P2P-DEVICE-FOUND -------*
2. p2p_prov_disc  pbc auto

   *Output: My laptop is visible on android peer devices list -------*
3. p2p_connect  pbc go_intent=15

   *Output: On Android device the connection state changes to INVITED -------*

I am not sure, if I am missing something.

Any help ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same issue. wpa_supplicant by default doesn't not enable wifi-p2p when compiled.

After re-compile and run wpa_supplicant with these lines 28-37:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/ics-plus-aosp/wpa_supplicant/README-P2P#28

then it was solved for me.
Hope it will help someone!